# How to add an additional XML element for polymorphic types with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I use JAXB for serializing java objects and I want the following XML output:

```xml
<attribute>
    <type>
        <listType>
            <itemType>
                <simpleType>
                    <dataLength>80</dataLength>
                    <dataType>string</dataType>
                    <decimalPlaces>0</decimalPlaces>
                </simpleType>
            </itemType>
        </listType>
    </type>
</attribute>
```

My java classes look like this:

**Attribute.java**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Attribute
{
    private Type type;

    public Type getType()
    {
        return this.type;
    }

    public void setType(Type type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

**Type.java**

```
public abstract class Type
{

}
```

**SimpleType.java**

```
public class SimpleType extends Type
{
    private int dataLength;

    private int decimalPlaces;

    private String dataType;

    // getters and setters...

}
```

**ListType.java**

```
public class ListType extends Type
{
    private Type itemType;

    // getters and setters...

}
```

**ComplexType.java**

```
public class ComplexType extends Type
{
    private List<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters and setters...

}
```

Without any additional annotations, JAXB produces this out:

```
<attribute>
    <type xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="listType">
        <itemType xsi:type="simpleType">
            <dataLength>80</dataLength>
            <dataType>string</dataType>
            <decimalPlaces>0</decimalPlaces>
        </itemType>
    </type>
</attribute>
```

I don't want the type information represented as an XML attribute (xsi:type), instead I want to have an additional XML element as shown in the XML code at the top. I think this is a typical use case, but I didn't find anything. Which possibilities do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have a problem if the class structure reflects the XML structure. Otherwise, JAXB needs the xsi:type to distinguish the polymorphic type field you have in the attribute object - how else could it reconstruct the POJO?

```
public class Type {
     private ListType listType;
}
public class ListType {
     private ItemType itemType;
}
public class ItemType {
     private SimpleType simpleType;
}
```

Comment: Small improvement to the solution. We use a generic TypeXml class with a type property. This class will then be used at several locations as XML specific properties.